# calculate the error of Lagrange Interpolation, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Construct Lagrange interpolating polynomials of degree two and three to approximate:
a)$ f (0.25)$ yes
$f(0.1) = -0.62049958, f(0.2) = -0.28398668,
f(0.3) = 0.00660095,
f(0.4) = 0.24842440
$

Additionally, you must calculate the error rate for each case.

Guys, I have done this exercise and obtained the following:
For the polynomial of degree two

$-2.438209x^2+4.1249808x-1.01145448$

when approaching $0.25$

$-2.438209(0.25)^2+4.1249808(0.25)-1.01145448= -0.1325973425$

This is what I have done:
For the polynomial of degree two, since 0.25 is between 0.2 and 0.4 I have taken as $x_0 = 0.2, x_1= 0.3, x_2= 0.4$
When doing the Interpolation I obtained the result of
$-2.438209^2+4.1249808x-1.01145448$ that when approximating it to the given value I obtained:

$-2.438209(0.25)^2+4.1249808(0.25)-1.01145448= -0.1325973425$

To calculate the error I have done the following:
Being the Lagrange error formula:

$error =| \frac{f'''(\xi)}{3!}(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2) |$

$error =| \frac{f'''(\xi)}{3!}(0.25-x_0)(0.25-x_1)(0.25-x_2)|$

Being the function

$f(x)= xcosx-2x^2+3x-1$
We calculate up to the third derivative of the function:
$f'(x)= x(-sin(x))-4x+cos(x)+3$
$f'''= -2(Sin(x)+2)-xcos(x)$
$f'''= xsin(x)-3cos(x)$
$f^{IV}= 4sin(x)-3cos(x)$
To evaluate the critical points of the function, the fourth derivative must be calculated, but since this function does not have critical points, what I did was evaluate the third derivative in the interval [0.2,0.4]
$f'''= (0.2)sin(0.2)-3cos(0.2)= -2.9992$
$f'''= (0.4)sin(0.4)-3cos(0.4)= -2.9971$
Then
$error =| \frac{-2.9971}{3!}(0.25-0.2)(0.25-0.3)(0.25-0.4)| $
$error =| \frac{-2.9971}{3!}(0.000375)| =0.0001873$
In the book it gives $0.0001109161632$

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that you're ignoring the value of $f(0.1)$. Can you elaborate on why that's allowed?

Comment: In the burden book they recommend doing it that way, that's why I did it that way, even when calculating the polynomial of degree two they take those points